# cascade validation form inside form

Tags: forms, validation, collections, cascade

I'm triying to use the cascade_validation inside a form, but it doesn't work.
I have an entity Formulario which have a colection of questions, so I insert the question form inside the Formulario form this way:

```
class FormularioType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('nombre')
            ->add('preguntasPonderadas', 'collection', array(
                'type'   => new QuestionType(),
                'allow_add'=>true,
                'allow_delete'=>true,
                'cascade_validation'=>true,
            ))
        ;       
    }
}
```

The entity question has an Assert like this:

```
class Question
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      min = 1,
     *      max = 5,
     *      minMessage = "El valor mínimo es 1",
     *      maxMessage = "El valor máximo es 5"
     * )
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="peso", type="integer")
     * 
     */
    private $peso;
}
```

The problem is that the range assert of the Question entity works if I create a Question from the Question form, but if I create a Question inside the Formulario form it doesn't work and permit numbers out of the range.
The empty field constraint does work, and the invalid type does work too (for example if I write a letter), even without using the cascade_validation.

The problem is that the range constraint doesn't work from the Formulario form.

Any idea?? Thansk a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should also add the `'cascade_validation' => true` in the `setDefaultOptions` function of your `FormularioType` class your to make it work.

```
/**
 * Sets the default options for this type.
 *
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver The resolver for the options.
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Formulario',
        'cascade_validation' => true
    ));
}
```